# About inserting dynamic data into the static content at run time

Tags: java

I have a template like this in properties file: `Dear xxxxxx, you are payment is succesfull.`

After loading this template from properties file, I want to replace that "xxxxxx" with dynamic data in Java class.

Please help me on this.

Comment: imagine u are redaing this question and have no idea what the problem is all about all u have is this question, will u be able to be helpful in precise manner? post ur code and the problem u r facing

Comment: `data.replace("xxxxxx", "dynamic data")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

placeholderReplacementMap is map that contain your static value and dynamic value key pair

```
Map<String, Object> placeholderReplacementMap = new HashMap<>();
StrSubstitutor substitutor = new StrSubstitutor(placeholderReplacementMap);
placeholderReplacementMap.put("xxxxxx", dynamicValue);

String newString = substitutor.replace("Dear xxxxxx","you are payment is succesful");
```

Comment: Thank you Vishnu Katpure

Answer (score 0):

I used Message.format("template",object array which is having dynamic data);